# Summing 5 objects after a where statement

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an active record of 5 objects as follows

```
@top_sold = Photo.where(photographer_id: @photog).order('qty_sold DESC').first(5)
```

I want to know the sum of qty_sold for all 5 photos

This isnt working

@top_sold.sum(:qty_sold)

Much thanks in adcance

Comment: Why isn't `@top_sold.sum(:qty_sold)` working?

Answer (score 1):

`.first` returns `Array`, use `limit` instead (which returns `ActiveRecord::Relation`).

```
@top_sold = Photo.where(photographer_id: @photog).order('qty_sold DESC').limit(5)
```

Comment: another solution would be to use `@top_sold.foldl(:+)` on your array. That way you can still use `.first(5)`

Answer (score 0):

for `Array` you can do

```
@top_sold.map(:qty_sold).inject(:+)
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried appending `sum` to your query?

```
@top_sold = Photo.where(photographer_id: @photog)
                 .order('qty_sold DESC').first(5).sum('qty_old')
```

If you need the original result set, then @Nithin answer is what you want to do.